# How to performe a RLIKE or REGEXP with Ebean?

Tags: playframework, orm, mariadb, ebean

I'd like to be able to search a column with a regexp using something like rlike(columnName, regexp) or regexp(columnName, regexp) with Ebean but I cannot figure out how to do it. What is the name of the method to perform such a request?

Comment: Is there a way to provide 'raw' SQL?

Comment: yes with raw("rlike()").

Comment: But `RLIKE` (and `REGEXP`) are not functions:  `WHERE col RLIKE '(this|that)'`

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.avaje.ebean.Model;
import play.Logger;
import utils.Hash;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    public static Model.Finder<Long, User> find = new Model.Finder<Long, User>(Long.class, User.class);
...
....
.....
}

public void foo(){
    User.find.where.like("propertyName", "%one_two%").findList();
}
```